# Enviar peticion ajax a datatables después de dejar de escribir

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

Requiero de hacer una peticion `ajax` a mi controlador después de haber escrito las palabras de búsqueda en mi `input` de [`datatables`](https://datatables.net/).

El punto al que quiero llegar es que no haga las peticiones por cada carácter escrito sino hasta que haya pasado un poco de tiempo de haber presionado la ultima tecla.

Este es mi código como esta declarada la tabla

```
var table = $('#tableComprobantes').dataTable({
    "order": [[5, "desc"]],
    "sDom": "<'row'<'col-xs-6'l><'col-xs-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-xs-6'i><'col-xs-6'p>>",
    "sPaginationType": "sangoma",
    "oLanguage": {
    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ comprobantes por página",
    "sInfo": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ comprobantes",
    "sInfoEmpty": "Sin comprobantes a mostrar",
    "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ comprobantes totales)",
    "sSearch": "Filtro:",
        "sZeroRecords": "Sin comprobantes encontrados"
    },
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/Portal/listComprobantes",
    "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        $('td:eq(7)', nRow).attr('align', 'center');
        $('td:eq(8)', nRow).attr('align', 'center');
        return nRow;
    },
    "aoColumns": [
        { "bSortable": false },
        { "bSortable": true },
        { "bSortable": true },
        { "bSortable": true },
        { "bSortable": true },
        { "bSortable": true },
        { "bSortable": true },
        { "bSortable": false },
        { "bSortable": false },
        { "bSortable": true }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer completamente como quieres de la siguiente manera:

Primero con unbind eliminas el evento por defecto del filtro (el de cada pulsación).

```
$('#x_filter input').unbind(); // 'x' es el nombre de tu tabla
```

Y después simplemente le añades el filtro al pulsar enter:

```
$('#x_filter input').bind('keyup', function(e) {
   if(e.keyCode == 13) {
   table.fnFilter(this.value);  // 'table' es la tabla, que has de tener iniciada.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la opción [`searchDelay`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searchDelay) (disponible a partir de la versión 1.10.3 de DataTables). Ésta es una traducción (propia) de la descripción en esa página web:

> La busqueda global incluida en DataTAbles (por defecto en la parte superior derecha de cada DataTable) buscará instantáneamente la tabla con cada tecla pulsada en el modo cliente y reduce la frecuencia de llamada automática a 400 milisegundos cuando se procesa en modo servidor. Esta frecuencia de llamada (*throttling*) puede controlarse usando el parámetro `searchDelay` en el procesado tanto del lado del cliente como del lado del servidor.
>
> [...]
>
> El valor dado a `searchDelay` estará en milisegundos (mS).

Entonces para usar `searchDelay`, sólo tendrías que añadir una nueva opción al crear el DataTable. Por ejemplo:

```
var table = $('#tableComprobantes').dataTable({
    ....
    searchDelay: 500,
    ....
});
```

Eso hará que se espere medio segundo (500 milisegundos) antes de realizar la petición de búsqueda AJAX al servidor.

Comment: Hice las pruebas pero siempre me manda una peticion en cuanto comienzo a escribir y al paso de 500ms vuelve a hacer otra peticion independientemente si sigo escribiendo no se si sea un bug o así es su funcionalidad